# Disable Migrations EntityFramework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

how can I disable completly the migrations of EntityFramework? I mean, what are the best practies when you are almost ready to go live with your web app? I'm worried that some automatic script reset my DB :)

Many thanks,
davide

Answer (score -1):

Migrations are normally used on the development database. For production I would suggest that you instead export an SQL script using the Update-Database -Script command which can then be run on your live database when you need to update it. It would be dangerous to have your development application pointing to a live DB and to run migrations directly.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to disable the migrations.